# Python. Создание экземпляров класса с уникальным полем

Tags: python, классы

есть класс с примерно такими полями

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, id_, time):
        self.id_ = id_
        self.time = [time]
```

не должно быть двух экземпляров с одинаковыми id(т.е. id - уникальное поле для экземпляров класса)

Если уже есть экземпляр с таким id, то необходимо сделать self.time.append(time)

какой есть способ создавать экземпляры класса в цикле (например, чтобы им присваивать имена?)

```
arr = []
for row in db:
    arr.append(A(row.id, row.time))
```

Как обратиться к экземпляру класса без имени по self.id, чтобы обновить список self.time

Answer (score 0):

Сохранять и получать объекты по ID, предотвращать их дублирование можно так:

```py
class A:
    all_objects = dict()

    def __init__(self, id_, time):
        self.id_ = id_
        self.time = [time]
        if id_ in A.all_objects:
            raise ValueError('Duplicate ID "%s"' % id_)
        A.all_objects[id_] = self

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_id(id_):
        return A.all_objects.get(id_)

A(22, 31415)
print(A.get_by_id(22).time)  # находит объект и выводит 31415
```

Вообще, судя по переменной `db`, Вы работаете с некой базой данных. В таком случае советую использовать какую-нибудь [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM), чтобы не изобретать велосипед. Например, [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/).